# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'locals'

Tags: python, anaconda, numba, jit

i tried to run some code on my gpu, to speed it up but i get this error message:

`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'locals'`

full error message:

```
  Nachricht = __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'locals'
  Quelle = C:\Users\User\Desktop\Schule\Informatik\Python\ImageGen\ImageGen\ImageGen.py
  Stapelüberwachung:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Schule\Informatik\Python\ImageGen\ImageGen\ImageGen.py", line 16, in <module> (Current frame)
    def func():
```

at line 16 of the code

i tried following this guide:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/running-python-script-on-gpu/

what am i doing wrong? or better, how can i fix this?

```
import numpy as np;
import math;
from PIL import Image;
import time;
from numba import jit, cuda;

#eq = ((x - offx)**2 + (y - offy)**2 - rd**2) / scale;
#eq = ((0.1*(x - offx))**3 - y + offy) / scale;
#eq = (np.sinh((x - offx) / scale) - (y - offy));
#eq = x - y;
#eq = (x - np.tan(y**2)) // scale;
#eq = np.arcsin(x) - np.cos(y) - x;
#eq = y + 2 * np.sin(2 * y) - np.sin(x) + 2 - x;

@jit(target ="cuda")
def func():
    for x1 in range(dim):
        for y1 in range(dim):
            x = (x1 - offx) / scale;
            y = (y1 - offy) / scale;
            eq = x - y;
            eq = eq * scale;
            if eq > 1:
                data[y1, x1] = [eq, 0, 0];
            elif eq < -1:
                eq = -eq;
                data[y1, x1] = [0, 0, eq];

if __name__=="__main__":

    n = 10000000;
    offx = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);
    offy = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);
    scale = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);
    x1 = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);
    y1 = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);
    x = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);
    y = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);
    eq = np.zeros(n, dtype = np.float64);

    dim = 2048;
    offy = dim/2;
    offx = dim/2;
    rd = dim/4;
    scale = dim/64;

    data = np.zeros((dim, dim, 3), dtype=np.uint8);

    func();

    print("[Done]");

    image = Image.fromarray(data);

    image.show();

    image.save("images/test " + str(time.time()) + ".png");
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message?

Comment: Nachricht = __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'locals'
  Quelle = C:\Users\User\Desktop\Schule\Informatik\Python\ImageGen\ImageGen\ImageGen.py
  Stapelüberwachung:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Schule\Informatik\Python\ImageGen\ImageGen\ImageGen.py", line 16, in <module> (Current frame)
    def func():

Comment: Please add this to your question by editing it.

Comment: BTW no semicolons in Python!

Comment: Klaus D. i used to code in a slightly different version from c++ , a bit in javascript and many programs in turbopascla. since then i just got used to semicolons and since python has no problem with them i will not stop using them (:

Comment: I don't know the library, but from the error it looks sorta like you need `def func(locals)`?

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work for me